# Problem with \includegraphics and dvisvgm

Tags: graphics, xetex, includegraphics, svg, dvisvgm

I'm using XeLatex and dvisvgm to produce a .svg file. I want to include a .png image with \includegraphics but it doesn't work: there is a replacement image instead of the one I want.

Here is what I use to compile (overleaf):

```
    END {
system("xelatex -no-pdf svgbeamer.tex && xelatex -no-pdf svgbeamer.tex && dvisvgm --font-format=ttf --exact --zoom=-1 -p1,- svgbeamer.xdv")
}
```

And here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm} %to get real fullscreen

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[height=8cm]{banane.png}

\end{document}
```

The same code compiled with only XeLatex works alright.

Any clue?

PS: the image is

[image]

Comment: does dvisvgm make any warnings?

Comment: I'm not sure where to look

Comment: Works for me. Note that unlike PDF, PNG is not physically embedded into the output SVG, only linked. Therefore, it should be present in the same directory as the final SVG.

Comment: Ah I get It, is it the case for any image file type?

Comment: Except PDF, yes. But it can be worked around. See answer.

Answer (score 3):

PNG (and other web compatible bitmap formats like JPEG and GIF) is not physically embedded into the SVG output by `dvisvgm`, only referenced via external link. Only PostScript and PDF (into which most static bitmap formats may be converted or wrapped using an external converter, such as ImageMagick) are. They remain separate and must be found by the Web browser during run-time.

To make SVG self-sufficient, bitmap files must be base64 encoded and embedded as `data:image/png;base64,...` data blob. This can be done as follows, patching the `graphicx` backend driver for `dvisvgm`.

This requires the `media4svg` package at a recent version (>= v0.9 2022-08-12).

Typeset with

```
dvilualatex svgbeamer
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 -p1,- svgbeamer
```

or

```
latex --shell-escape svgbeamer
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 -p1,- svgbeamer
```

or

```
xelatex --no-pdf --shell-escape svgbeamer
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 -p1,- svgbeamer.xdv
```

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%\graphicspath{{myimages}} % add search dirs as needed

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% patch graphics backend driver `dvisvgm.def' to physically embed
% bitmaps into DVI
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\Ginclude@bitmapOrig\Ginclude@bitmap
\def\Ginclude@bitmap#1{%
  \baseSixtyFour{#1}{72}{{?nl}}\bitmap@stream%
  \Ginclude@bitmapOrig{%
    data:image/\expandafter\remove@dot\Gin@ext;;base64,{?nl}%
    \bitmap@stream}%
}
\def\remove@dot.#1;{#1}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{media4svg} % provides base64-encode utility
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\baseSixtyFour#1#2#3#4{
  \sys_if_engine_luatex:TF{
    \xdef#4{\directlua{media4svg.base64("#1",#2,"#3")}}
  }{
    \msvg_convert_file_to_blob:nnnN{#1}{#2}{#3}#4
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Embedded PNG}
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{banane.png}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be useful to add something for base64 encoding to `l3kernel`?

Comment: Yes, I think such a tool could come in handy from time to time. Is it possible to read arbitrary binary files bytewise without Lua?